# How to run Azure Application Insights in developer mode for Javascript (node.js)

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-application-insights

I've read documents in Azure (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics#debug) But couldn't see how to enable Developer Mode for application insights.

How can I enable Developer Mode in Azure Application Insights for node.js?

Answer (score 4):

Developer Mode in the .NET Application Insights SDK does a couple of things, primarily enabling debug messages and disabling batching of telemetry.

While the Node SDK doesn’t have a single setting that does this, you can get the same behavior by using both of the following settings together:

`appInsights.setup(...).setInternalLogging(true, true)` to enable debug messages

`appInsights.defaultClient.config.maxBatchSize = 1` to disable batching

For the second command, make sure to replace `appInsights.defaultClient` for your own TelemetryClient instance if you've instantiated your own.

Comment: The [recommendation from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics#debug) is to use a `maxBatchSize` of `0`

Answer (score 2):

According to the official doc (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics#debug), currently, Developer Mode for application insights is only supported in C# and Visual Basic

Answer (score 2):

As per the source code [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-node.js/blob/bf66555ad51f2e312866088cd1e006a73f04ee06/applicationinsights.ts#L243):

[image]

Then in your code, you should use the code as below:

```
const appInsights = require("applicationinsights");
appInsights.setup("<instrumentation_key>").setInternalLogging(true, true);
appInsights.start();
```

Comment: Hi thank you its a good find. I tried this but I expect to see the results faster in developer mode which did not happen. I see texts like these in console:

    asd asd 
ApplicationInsights:Sender [ { method: 'POST',
    withCredentials: false,
    headers:
     { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-json-stream',
       'Content-Encoding': 'gzip',
       'Content-Length': 634 } } ]
ApplicationInsights:Sender [ '{"itemsReceived":6,"itemsAccepted":6,"errors":[]}' ]